# Does having a directory structure slow down file retrieval on a windows file system?

Tags: c#, file-io

Say i have thousands of files.  Is it better to have one folder to store the files or is it better to have sub folders?

What is better for c# program to locate a retrieve files (from a performance pov)?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that if you always know the path to a file eg: path = (configuredRoot + path + filename) retreiving files should be the same for all paths. If you have to recursively search for files, having these in folders would obviously slow down the process of finding them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the path is known and a search of the directory contents is performed to find the next subdirectory/the desired file, using subdirectories would be more efficient from an asymptotic point of view, much the same way that binary search trees give results much faster than linked lists in the worst case scenario. I don't know if my assumption about the file system is correct, though.

Answer (score 0):

The NTFS directory structure is a B+Tree, so I don't see any reason a directory of essentially any size would be less efficient than a tree-like directory structure.

For example if your files are similar to `XX-YYYY-ZZZZZZZZ` then you might store them in a three-level structure like:

```
01
  01-0123
      01-0123-01234567
      01-0123-01234568
      01-0123-01234569
  01-1123
      01-1123-01234567
      01-1123-01234568
      01-1123-01234569
02
  02-1123
      02-0123-01234567
      02-0123-01234568
      02-0123-01234569
```

On a filesystem such as exFAT you will get a significant win in this way, because you are using the directory structure to avoid a linear scan of the directory entries.

But on NTFS the directory entries are stored in a B+Tree so they are actually already organized like this internally.

So I suspect that on NTFS (or other filesystems using B trees internally) you will not get any significant advantages.

There may even be a penalty, (but I expect that the penalty will be small).